# JPanel.addComponentListener does not work when the listener is a class variable

Tags: java, listener, listeners, event-listener

I have a public class which has the following method and instance variable:

```
public void setImagePanel(JPanel value) {
  imagePanel = value;

  if (imagePanel != null) {

     //method 1 : works
     imagePanel.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent evt) {
           System.out.println("Here 1");
        }

     });

     //method 2 :  does not work
     panelResizeListener = new ResizeListener();
     imagePanel.addComponentListener(panelResizeListener);

     //method 3 : works
     //ResizeListener listener = new ResizeListener();
     //imagePanel.addComponentListener(listener);

     //method 4 : works
     //imagePanel.addComponentListener(new ResizeListener());

     //method 5 : does not work -- THIS IS THE DESIRED CODE I WANT TO USE
     imagePanel.addComponentListener(panelResizeListener);
  }
}

public class ResizeListener extends ComponentAdapter {

  @Override
  public void componentResized(ComponentEvent evt) {
     System.out.println("RESIZE 3");
  }

}

private ResizeListener panelResizeListener = new ResizeListener();
private static JPanel imagePanel;
```

Each of the methods above correspond the to code immediately below until the next //method comment.  What i don't understand is why i can't use the class instance variable and add that to the `JPanel` as a component listener.

What happens in the cases above where i say that the method does not work is that i don't get the `"RESIZE 3"` log messages.  In all cases where i list that it works, then i get the `"RESIZE 3"` messages.

The outer class is public with no other modification except that it implements an interface that i created (which has no methods or variables in common with the methods and variables listed above).

If anyone can help me i would greatly appreciate it.  This problem makes no sense to me, the code should be identical.

Comment: You can use a class variable. There is something else wrong with your code. Post your SSCCE: http://sscce.org

Comment: Sorry, i don't follow, i am using a class variable and it's in the code i posted above.  What do you mean something else is wrong with my code?

I also tried the following


     ResizeListener listener = new ResizeListener();
     panelResizeListener = listener;//HAVING THIS LINE IN BREAKS IT, I don't understand why
     imagePanel.addComponentListener(listener);

Also a side question, I don't know how to format my posts as code, i have tried looking at the edits of other people, and it looks like they just add spaces in front, but it doesn't work for me, thx.

Comment: You didn't post a SSCCE (I gave you a link that explains what it is), I can't tell you whats wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man camickr, you were right.  Man this was a weird one to solve.  There was something else wrong with my code.  The order of the methods calls into my class resulted in me adding the listener then another method would end up removing the listener referenced by that variable so of course i would never get events.  Thanks a lot for all the help ppl.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you're declaring panelResizeListener after you're using it.  That normally kills just about anything.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i figured out what the problem was.